# Multi Network Browsing

Tags: networking, internet, browser

I have 2 networks setup at home and at work, one is broadband and another is wifi. I usually browse the internet using two browser. I want the two browsers to use different connections, lighening up my internet load. I don't know the exact search keyword for this, and i haven't seen it done before. Can somebody point me to the right direction. It doen't need to be OS specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an application for Windows call [Forcebind](http://old.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) that will do what you want.  The only downside is that you will need to launch your programs from the software every time you want to do this.  It has no GUI so you will need to punch in the path to the .exe file of the browser every time.  If you have the commands ready in a text document it should go pretty fast once you get used to it though.

[Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/117890/how-to-force-an-application-to-use-a-specific-network-card/) is a link to a walkthrough of how to get set up and use the software from the command prompt.